# How to properly band-pass filter an autocorrelated signal?

Tags: python, frequency-response, autocorrelation, bandpass

Let's consider an example ECG time series, sampled at 360Hz:

[image]

I verified that autocorrelating a signal preserves its frequency content. For instance, both original and autocorrelated data show the same peak frequency:

[image]

However, I noticed that **band-pass filtering the autocorrelated signal** does not yield the same results as **autocorrelating the band-pass filtered signal**, using the same BPF corner frequencies (between 2 and 100Hz in this example):

[image]

As a matter of fact, it looks like I would be better off multiplying the band-pass filtered autocorrelated signal by -1 to match the autocorrelated band-pass filtered signal:

[image]

Is it possible to select the post-autocorrelation band-pass filtering parameters to get both these signals to match?

---

My Python code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter


def autocorr(x):
    result = np.correlate(x, x, mode='same')
    return result

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

ecg = electrocardiogram()
plt.plot(ecg)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
ax1.psd(ecg,360)
ax1.set_title('PSD of original ECG data')
ax1.axvline(0.3333, linestyle='--')
ax2.psd(autocorr(ecg),360)
ax2.set_title('PSD of autocorrelated ECG data')
ax2.axvline(0.3333, linestyle='--')


autocorreated_filtered_ecg=autocorr(butter_bandpass_filter(ecg, 2, 100, 360, 5))
filtered_autocorrelated_ecg=butter_bandpass_filter(autocorr(ecg), 2, 100, 360, 5)

plt.plot(autocorreated_filtered_ecg, label='autocorrelated + BPF')
plt.plot(filtered_autocorrelated_ecg, label='BPF + autocorrelated')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(53900,58000)

plt.plot(autocorreated_filtered_ecg, label='autocorrelated + BPF')
plt.plot(-filtered_autocorrelated_ecg, label='-1 * (BPF + autocorrelated)')
plt.legend()
plt.xlim(53900,58000)
```

Comment: *I verified that autocorrelating a signal preserves its frequency content* but that's a false claim. It seems to look superficially the same, in your very specific case. Mathematically, there's no doubt that the spectrum of the autocorrelation function of a signal needs to be different.

Comment: Maybe you'll want to tell us why you think you should be applying signal processing methods such as filtering to an autocorrelation function? It's honestly not obvious to me, and while I really find the thought very interesting, I can't find an application. You do seem to have one – mind telling us *why* you're doing this?

Comment: *However, I noticed that band-pass filtering the autocorrelated signal does not yield the same results as autocorrelating the band-pass filtered signal,* unsurprisingly, you can't change the order of operations if one is linear and the other is not and get the same result!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Marcus. To give you a bit of context, I am processing seismic data created using a continuous seismic source. These data are autocorrelated, deconvolved and THEN band-pass filtered.
I am trying to model these data using synthetic wavelets and I am wondering whether it is acceptable to band-pass filter the *modelled* data with the same frequencies as those used on the *measured* data following autocorrelation and deconvolution.
Using the ECG was a mere attempt at creating a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: but **why** are they autocorrelated, then deconvoluted and then band-pass filtered? This seems to make very little sense to me! It might make a lot of sense to you, but I'm a newbie to seismology, so I can't really tell why this is done, and thus I couldn't help with the wavelet aspects of things :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Isn't the spectrum of the autocorrelation the PSD? And the (squared magnitude of) the spectrum of the original signal is the periodogram, which is also an estimate of the PSD. So I don't think the two should look that different...but correct me if I am wrong.
EDIT: Of course this is in the unfiltered case. If you filter _after_ autocorrelation, obviously it is as you say and the spectra cannot match.

Comment: mateC: "Spectrum" is a bit of an underdefined term, but usually Spectrum == PSD, in my terms. The *Fourier transform* of the ACF is indeed the PSD.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: in conventional seismic, you deal with a source of finite duration, which makes it possible to identify primary and multiple arrivals in the raw data by analyzing their travel times. 
However, the issue with a continuous source is that it is not "localized" in time, thus making it impossible to identify these events in the raw data.
By computing the similarity of the trace with itself, the autocorrelation allows center the "primary" event on zero.
This autocorrelation step is followed by a one-sided deconvolution to get rid of the acausal events.

Comment: The references that I am working with (*e.g.* Malusa *et al.*, 2002) mention an additional band-pass filtering step performed *after* the correlation-deconvolution. 
I would rather band-pass filter the data prior to correlation-deconvolution. I am still trying to make sense of this, hence my attempt at comparing the BPF before and after autocorrelation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to select the post-autocorrelation band-pass filtering parameters to get both these signals to match?

No, since forming the autocorrelation function of a real signal is going to do squaring operations on the spectrum, you can't apply a linear filter to implement the same nonlinear distortion.